# Configure windows Authentication in IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication, windows-server-2012, intranet, iis-8.5

I searched enough but couldn't find a solution. I have a ASP.NET Intranet app at Windows Server 2008 IIS 7.5 with windows authentication - this all work great.

I have been trying to migrate it to Windows Server 2012. I have already installed Windows Authentication role for the server and already enabled the windows authentication for the web site.

The application seems to be working fine for my account but if anybody else try to connect they get windows login popup.

Comment: Give access to the users then. Windows Authentication doesn't mean that anyone gets access automatically. Unless you give permissions to specific users or groups, no-one will be able to login

Comment: But with Windows Server 2008 IIS 7.5, I don't have to do that. The Intranet  app had windows authentication with custom role. I never added anybody to that server.

Comment: You *do* actually. Someone set the proper permissions there, otherwise no-one would be able to login. Perhaps web.config had an entry that allowed access to all users. You *don't* get free access by default in any IIS version

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues.  I wrote up this answer:

- [How to enable Windows Authentication on a Windows Server 2012 IIS website using Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554106/how-to-enable-windows-authentication-on-a-windows-server-2012-iis-website-using)

Short answer is:

- Ensure you have `Web-Windows-Auth` installed
- Ensure `Set-WebConfigurationProperty` has been set for Windows Authentication (and I turned off Anonymous Authentication too)
- Ensure your Web.Config is properly setup

The biggest difference is IIS has turned this off by default, and you have to explicitly enable it to use it, even though your Web.Config is configured correctly.